# How to automatically create BibTex citations for R packages in knitr file?

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave, bibtex

I am not sure whether this an R, LaTeX, or BibTex problem.

I am trying to automatically generate a .bib file containing citations for R packages and then list them at the end. I am able to generate the BibTex file and I don't see anything wrong with the BibTex file, but the entries don't appear when I compile the PDF.

I'm not sure if R is not producing a BibTex file correctly, if some LaTeX syntax is wrong, or if the BibTex file needs to be pre-compiled or whatever. I noticed that `\bibliography{NOT A REAL FILENAME}` will produce a References section without complaining, but I don't think that is the problem.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[margin=1in, headheight=20pt, footskip=20pt]{geometry}

\begin{document}

<<label='Create References'>>=
require(knitr) # Needed for write_bib()

# Load some packages to the session:
require(xtable)
require(ggplot2)

# Select packages to cite:
citPkgs <- names(sessionInfo()$otherPkgs)
# Write the bibtex file:
write_bib(citPkgs, file="R-Pckgs.bib")
@

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{R-Pckgs.bib}

\end{document}
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: just to clarify, `write_bib()` is a function in `knitr`; `knitcitations` has `write.bibtex()`

Comment: @Yihui, thank you. I have corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just replace `\bibliography{R-Pckgs.bib}` with `\bibliography{R-Pckgs}`, and it should work fine.

On Windows 7, with an up-to-date MikTeX installation and current R and R packages, the following worked:

1. Put your reproducible example in a file named `"eg.Rnw"` and edit to remove the extraneous `".bib"`
2. Launch R and navigate to the directory in which `"eg.Rnw"` is located.
3. Do `library(knitr); knit2pdf("eg.Rnw")`

**Note:** There are obviously many workflows for going from `*.Rnw` to `*.pdf`, but if you want to use `knit2pdf()` (at least), make sure that you run it from the directory containing the `*.Rnw` to be processed.

Comment: Thanks. I tried removing ".bib" and it now seems to work sometimes.

Comment: Jupp, this works for me, too. However if I use the `Compile pdf` Button in RStudio (convenience...) this doesn't work. I am using texlive.

Comment: @EDi -- Doesn't turn out to be so convenient, does it ;) Thanks for leaving that comment, though, as I realize lots of folks have added that additional layer to their R environment, often as it does bite...

Answer (score 4):

Add a `\nocite{dummycite}` to your document - to create a citation so that the bibliography is printed.

Note that this is obsolete if you already have other citation in your document.

Comment: Does BibTex not work if there isn't at least one proper citation?

Comment: Seems like it thinks: 'There are no citations in the doc, so why create a bibliography?'

Comment: the idea makes sense, but I wish there was better support for "references" vs "citations"