# Non-valid bibtex from knitr write_bib

Tags: r, knitr, bibtex

I'm trying to get knitr to create a bibtex file that includes all the packages that I am using as shown (and answered) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432448/how-to-automatically-create-bibtex-citations-for-r-packages-in-knitr-file). That part is working fine but a single R package, `foreach`, results in non-valid bibtex code.

Here is a minimal `.Rnw` example that produces the error

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}

This is a test

<<>>=
library(foreach)

# Write the bibtex file:
write_bib("foreach", file="test.bib")
@

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

kniting this file produces this `test.bib` file

```
@Manual{R-foreach,
  title = {foreach: Provides Foreach Looping Construct for R},
  author = {{Revolution Analytics} and Steve Weston}},
  year = {2015},
  note = {R package version 1.4.3},
  url = {https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=foreach},
}
```

Note that the author line has two curly braces towards the end of the author line so using this bibtex file without removing the curly brace results in a bunch of problems. I've only encountered this problem with the `foreach` package.

Can anyone tell me what I can do to prevent the error (currently I have a one-line `sed` code to remove the extra brace)?

The `citation("foreach")` output looks fine and dandy, so I'm guessing the error may be deep down in `utils:::toBibtex.bibentry` but I haven't been able to figure it out.